# ¿Como habilitar sockets en Hostinger?

Tags: php, servidor, socket

Tengo una página web de prueba donde realizo pruebas de chat la cuestión es que en el localhost no tengo problema en acceder a  la consola para habilitar los sockets mi duda es exactamente esa como puedo hacer para habilitar sockets en el servidor de hostinger.

investigando en su página oficial (https://www.hostinger.es/como/se-admiten-sockets) lo unico que encontre fue lo siguiente

> Soportamos solamente sockets salientes. Si te estás conectando, debería funcionar., Sin embargo, no permitimos que los clientes se enlacen a los puertos locales para las conexiones entrantes.

No tengo muy claro todo sobre sockets así que no se a que se refiere con eso.
Lo único que quiero saber es si es posible activar esa clase de sockets para chat en el servidor de Hostinger. y de ser así como lo hago.

Comment: Tu pregunta me parece tiene problemas de formato y puede terminar cerrada, ¿qué has intentado o investigado? por que estás colocando múltiples empresas de hosting

Comment: Actualize un poco mi pregunta no se si este más claro así

Comment: a lo mejor tiene que ver con esto: _La ubicación predeterminada para el archivo de socket Unix que el servidor utiliza para la comunicación con clientes locales es /tmp/mysql.sock (si éste no funciona, intente /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock)._